# Quantos porcento N item representa no total geral - Consulta

Tags: sql, firebird

Bom dia, estou criando um relatório da curva ABC porém sou iniciante e ainda estou com algumas dificuldades.

Tenho uma tabela chamada: ITENS.
Com os campos: COD_ITEM, QuantidadeVenda, ValorUnitario, Subtotal, Descricao

Com uma consulta SQL consegui trazer o valor total de vendas:

```
SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS SUBTOTAL FROM ITENS
ORDER BY SUBTOTAL
```

E com outra consulta que não entendi porque não deu certo, traz os campos que pedi porém eles não são "somados" ficando vários registros do mesmo item.

```
SELECT COD_ITEM, QuantidadeVenda, Descricao, ValorUnitario, 
Subtotal FROM ITENS
GROUP BY COD_ITEM, QuantidadeVenda, Descricao, ValorUnitario, 
Subtotal
```

O que precisaria realmente trazer é um select que mostre comparado ao total de vendas quantos % representa cada item

Comment: Informe o BD pois alguns tem ferramentas nativas que facilitam este tipo de consulta.

Comment: Então aqui é o IBExpert

Comment: O firebird, esse é o pra gerenciar éerr

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/tem-como-fazer-isso-no-firebird/59910  ajudou ?

Comment: @WSS: Qual é a versão do Firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avalie se o código abaixo atende ao que necessita.

```
-- código #1
SELECT A.COD_ITEM, A.Subtotal,
       (A.Subtotal / B.Total * 100) as Perc
  from (SELECT COD_ITEM, sum(SUBTOTAL) as Subtotal
          from ITENS 
          group by COD_ITEM) as A
       cross join
       (SELECT sum(SUBTOTAL) as Total
          from ITENS) as B;
```

Ou então:

```
-- código #2
with A as (
SELECT COD_ITEM, sum(SUBTOTAL) as Subtotal
  from ITENS 
  group by COD_ITEM
),
B as (
SELECT sum(SUBTOTAL) as Total
  from ITENS
)
SELECT A.COD_ITEM, A.Subtotal,
       (A.Subtotal / B.Total * 100) as Perc
  from A cross join B;
```

Comment: Obrigado José, em cima do que me enviou conseguimos outras possibilidades! Grato.